# Changing capsule radius in ThreeJs

Tags: javascript, three.js

i have successfully run [fps example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=first#games_fps) in threeJs locally, then went to mess around a bit.
Imported my colleague 3d assets then noticed that the asset are too big to be expected. Downscaling the asset are a solution but i want to scale the player, looked around and found it [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/games_fps.html#L119). changed it value from 0.35 to 4 and its a success.

The problem. How do i make the capsule radius thinner but still have the same height? Or, how to make the camera felt bigger to match capsule radius? Because what i did was made the capsule collision's radius bigger it collide with objects that is quite far away from the camera perspective.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can look at the capsule source code to see how to change its radius: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/math/Capsule.js